# Explicit member method reference in Java

Tags: java, coding-style, code-readability

Based on the following example :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ExempleJFrame extends JFrame {

    public ExempleJFrame() {
        super("JFrame example");
        setLocation(50, 50);
        setSize(200, 200);
        getContentPane().add(new JLabel("This is a text label!", SwingConstants.CENTER));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExempleJFrame frame = new ExempleJFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to make it more explicit that I am calling a member method (see `setLocation()` and `setSize()`)?

I am looking for something in the lines of `this.setLocation()` to make it explicit that I call a member method and not something from outer space.

Comment: so what prevents you from doing like you say => this.setX()?

Comment: My question is : is it possible to do it, since all examples I have found don't do it like that

Comment: If `setLocation()` is a member inherited form `JFrame`, use `super.setLocation()`. If it is defined in `ExempleJFrame` use `this.setLocation()`, simple as that.

Comment: @Less : is it considered a good practice to do it like this? or am I looking to add useless noise?

Comment: Are you actually worried that using `this` pointer for invocation can introduce some overhead? This would be the only "noise" I could care about, and that is not the case, AFAIK. So, you are completely free to use `this` or `super`, and make your code more readable and nice looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, you can set a Save Action (Additional Save Actions -> Member Accesses -> Use 'this' qualifier for method accesses'), which will automatically convert `setLocation` to `this.setlocation` on save.

Personally I don't find it particularly useful, because a non-prefixed method call can only be either

- a static method call (which will be italic in Eclipse)
- a this member call
- a super member call

The last two rarely need to be distinguished IMHO, because of run time dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

The good practice is to [favour composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components): don't extend `JFrame` but delare a `JFrame yourFrame;` member in your class instead. Then you call the JFrame methods naturally with:

```
yourFrame.someMethod();
```

ps: and call your GUI methods [from the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            yourFrame = new JFrame("JFrame example");
            initFrame();
            yourFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as other said in the comments you could use `this.setwatever()`. usually it is considered a good practice to use `this.membervariable` but never really came accross code using this.method().but it works perfectly fine.