# how to extend JFrame in a class that already extends Thread

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jframe

I have a class that extends Thread,  and need to extend JFrame on the same class.  since multiple inheritance is not possible in Java,  how do it use JFrame objects inside of a class that already extends Thread?

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Why extend `JFrame`?

Comment: Why do you need to extend JFrame in the first place? It is usually not necessary.

Comment: See this question on extending JFrame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components

Comment: You should usually extend ***neither*** JFrame or Thread. Problem solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of extending either JFrame or Thread, use composition, it is a lot less limiting:

```
public class MyApplication {
    JFrame applicationFrame;

    Thread someThread;

    MyApplication() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override void run() {
                applicationFrame = new JFrame();

                // some more GUI initialization.
                applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        someThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override void run() {
                // do my work.
            }
        });

        someThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        new MyApplication();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than extending Thread, can you make the class implement Runnable? This way, you could extend JFrame instead, pass it to a Thread.

```
public class MyFrameThread extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyFrameThread());
    myThread.start();
    myThread.join();
}
```

Comment: extending JFrame is bad idea in general

Comment: i am making a socket program in java.  my only experience is in Android so java swing is vary different from what I am used to.  so instead of extending JFrame I will make console application without any GUI.  I am doing this to test some code for sockets that i will later use in Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JFrames and Threads easily without extending them, and as has been suggested by most, you are usually *better* off **not** extending them. Extending them binds your class to the JFrame preventing you from later using it in a JPanel, JDialog, etc. Why restrict yourself like this if not necessary?