# JMenuBar Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java

I am just started learning Java and I've been reading through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#menubarapi) documentation. I don't like to copy a bunch of code and paste it. So I have been trying to work my way through the documentation one thing at at time.

I already have a working JFrame and decided I would start by adding a menu.

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
package mainframe;

import javax.swing.*;

public class menuBar extends JMenuBar {
    JMenuBar mainMenu = JMenuBar("Menu");
}
```

MY ERROR:

```
error: cannot find symbol
  JMenuBar mainMenu = JMenuBar("Menu");
  symbol:   method JMenuBar(String)
  location: class menuBar
1 error
```

So anyways. I am not really sure what the "cannot find symbol error" means. Maybe I am searching wrong. But every time I Google it it takes me to more complex questions with no clear answer. Any advice as to what I am doing wrong and or to what the cannot find symbol error means would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your particular code here, I suggest that you do not extend the `JMenuBar` class.  You may have seen it in many tutorials or examples where the `JFrame` class is extended, although that is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components).  To add a `JMenuBar` to your window, I would suggest doing the following:

```
public class MyProgram {
    JFrame frame;
    public MyProgram() {
        ...
        frame = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Open..."));
        mainMenu.add(fileMenu); // adds a single JMenu to the menubar
        frame.setJMenuBar(mainMenu); // adds the entire menubar to the window
        ...
        frame.setVisible();
        ...
    }
```

The only reason you would extend the `JMenuBar` class would be if you wanted to make a class that had additional functionality in terms of methods defined in your subclass, but that seems unlikely especially given the fact that you're just learning Swing.

Comment: You shouldn't extend `JFrame` either; that is bad practice.

Comment: Ah my bad, if I'd paid closer attention I wouldn't have put the `extends JFrame` there.  That also makes it hard to understand the origins of `add` and how `addActionListener(this)` fails while `addMouseListener(this)` works.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I really appreciate all the time you took to explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `JMenuBar` never takes any arguments.  Also remember to use the `new` keyword when you instantiate (create an instance of) a new object.  Consider using the following code:

```
JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
mainMenu.add(fileMenu);
```

Comment: What is mainMenu.add() referenceing? Is mainMenu suppose to represent the package?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck JMenuBar.add(JMenu) adds a JMenu to the JMenuBar.  When you create the JMenuBar in the first line, it is initially empty.  You build a JMenu (adding JMenuItems to it), and then add that JMenu to the JMenuBar.

Comment: Okay the reason I ask is because I get "package mainMenu does not exist" on the last line. Anyways. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
JMenuBar mainMenu = JMenuBar("Menu");
```

should be

```
JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar("Menu");
```

You forgot the `new` keyword. You must always use `new` when creating a new object with a constructor. Otherwise, Java will think that it is a method, which it is not.

Furthermore, if you look at the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html). you will find that `JMenuBar`'s constructor does not take any arguments. Therefore, don't pass anything:

```
JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
```

Comment: Okay.. well that at least got me a different error. ----- error: constructor JMenuBar in class JMenuBar cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck That means that you aren't giving the right arguments. Are you *sure* that `JMenuBar`'s constructor accepts a `String`?

Comment: The `JMenuBar` class only has one constructor, and it doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: No I think I just threw that in there when I was trying to get it to work. I believe it is just a container for the actual menu. Thanks

Comment: Kris, regarding your error `constructor JMenuBar in class JMenuBar cannot be applied to given types`, that is possibly because you are trying to extend the `JMenuBar` class without implementing your own constructor.