# Extending from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, extend

Is there a difference from extending to `JFrame` and `javax.swing.JFrame`?

Example:

```
public class Authenticator extends JFrame {
```

and...

```
public class Authenticator extends javax.swing.JFrame {
```

Comment: ***Don't*** extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143923/758280

Comment: if you have another class call `JFrame` then you need to identify with package you want to use

Comment: @AndrewThompson Why? I always used to extend the GUI class to `JFrame`, it makes things easier for me, but i didn't know it is considered a bad practice, why is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: @BackSlash  Do you extend `JButton` or `JLabel` when you need either?  See the link by Jeffrey for more technical reasons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No i don't extend `JButton` or `JLabel` i just extend `JFrame` the class i want to use for GUI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes no difference unless you have another class called `JFrame` and are importing it instead of `javax.swing.JFrame`.

That said, as Andrew Thompson said, you shouldn't extend `JFrame`, you should use an instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you import **javax.swing.JFrame;** then you use
**public class Authenticator extends JFrame {**
if not then use
**public class Authenticator extends jvax.swing.JFrame {**

But the second method is mostly used when you have classes with same name in different pakage, to differentiate the  classes.

for example
[-]mypackage
  |----[-]pakage1
                                    |---TestClass.java
 |----[-]pakage2
                |---TestClass.java

Here is the situation we have a package named mypackage and two sub packages pakage1 and pakage2

now if we just import it will give this

```
import mypackage.pakage1.TestClass;
import mypackage.pakage2.TestClass;
class Testw
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
System.out.println("Swah!");
}
}
```

it will give following error

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin>javac Testw.java
Testw.java:2: mypackage.pakage1.TestClass is already defined in a single-type import
import mypackage.pakage2.TestClass;
^
1 error
```

so what you do?

In this case you use the second method which is also called fully quailfied name
now you import one pakage and use fully qualified name for other.

```
import mypackage.pakage1.TestClass;
class Testw
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
TestClass  testclass1 = new TestClass();
mypackage.pakage2.TestClass  testclass2 = new  mypackage.pakage2.TestClass();
System.out.println("Swah!");
}
}
```

So the summery of whole thing is that fully qualified name is used when their is name clashing, we can also use this method when their is no name clashing ,their will be no -ve effect on program

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your import. If you import javax.swing.JFrame, no.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import `JFrame` anyway, and it will be from `javax.swing` package most likely, you only need to write the whole package path if there are multiple `JFrame` classes included, so the compiler will know which one you want to use, so if there's only one `JFrame` class, then the import is enough, you don't have to specify it again