# How to use extended class as variable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, messagedialog

My problem is hopefully simple to solve and I believe is just a lack of my Java knowledge. I've probably used the wrong terminology in the title. I'm sorry about that.
Basically, I'm using Java swing and my frame is a class (public className extends JFrame). I need to use the frame somewhere else. How do I do that?
I have tried using `JFrame frame = main.Window` but have been told it cannot be resolved to a variable. So how do I use it?

Comment: `I need to use the frame somewhere else` What this it means? a new instance? the same instance? Show some valid code(as short as possible) demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [don't extend `JFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components). What you probably need to do is have a *field* in your class which is a `JFrame`.

To provide access to this field from another class, add a *getter* method to your class and ensure you pass a reference to your class to the other class. E.g.

```
public class Name {
  private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

  public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, decide what other classes may wish to do with your frame and provide specific methods in your class to support this. e.g.

```
public void makeFrameVisible() {
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```