# Border Layout Conflicting with Grid Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, border-layout

I have 3 `JPanel` components. Panel 1 is set to `BorderLayout.NORTH`, panel 2 is set to `BorderLayout.CENTER` and panel 3 is set to `BorderLayout.SOUTH`.

Now panel 1 has a `GridLayout(1,2)` and panel 2 also has `GridLayout(1,2)`.
The thing that bothers me is in panels 1 and 2 the components are aligned as though they are in `GridLayout` combined.

To be specific I have a set of `JTextField` components in panel 1 in position at row=0 and column=1.

I have a `JTable` inside `JScrollPane` at position row=0 and column=1 in panel 2.

Both these components are being rendered with the same dimension no matter what I try.

The code is too long to post here and I would appreciate if someone can clarify how to conceptually solve this problem.

```
public class PanelTest extends JFrame{
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new PanelTest();
    }
    public PanelTest() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
        textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
        textField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        panel1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 100));

        panel1.add(textField1);
        panel1.add(textField2);

        JTable table = new JTable();
        //... 
        JScrollPane jps1 = new JScrollPane(table);
        jps1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(10); 
        JScrollPane jps2 = new JScrollPane(textField3);

        panel2.add(jps1);
        panel2.add(jps2);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Using GridBagLayout:

```
  public PanelTest() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,200));
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,200));
   JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
    textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
    JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
    textField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    panel1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 100));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //      gbc.insets = new Insets(5,100,5,1);
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    panel1.add(textField1, gbc);
    gbc.gridx=1;
    panel1.add(textField2, gbc);

    JTable table = new JTable();
    //... 
    JScrollPane jps1 = new JScrollPane(table);
    jps1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
    jps1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
    JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(); 

    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //      gbc.insets = new Insets(5,100,5,1);
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    panel2.add(jps1, gbc);
    gbc.gridx=1;
    panel2.add(textField3, gbc);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.pack();
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a **[runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** which demonstrates your problem. **This is not a code dump**, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It is hard to imagine what layout you want to get, and moreover to reproduce your current code to analise the problem. So runnable example is needed.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: I have edited above question and added some code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The thing that bothers me is in panels 1 and 2 the components are aligned as though they are in GridLayout combined.

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid):

> `GridLayout simply makes a bunch of components equal in size and displays them in the requested number of rows and columns.`

"It will display them in equal size", so, if you have 2 columns and your `JFrame`'s size is 900px, you will have 2 components of 450px each, if you had 3 then it will be 3 components of 300px each.

That's why you should [avoid the use of setPreferred|maximum|minimum size methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) and let the Layout Manager choose the dimensions for you or if you really really need a fixed size, you should instead override the `getPreferred|maximum|minimum` size as said by @trashgod in his answer.

You probably want to use a [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) instead or a different [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) such as [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) or [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and combine them.

You also should [avoid extending `JFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components) unless it's extremely necessary.

Since you didn't posted how the UI should look like, I can imagine you wanted something like this:

[image]

Which is done with the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class LayoutManagerExample {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pane1, pane2, pane3;
    JTextField field1, field2, field3;
    JTable table;
    JScrollPane jsp;
    LayoutManagerExample() {
        frame = new JFrame("LayoutManagerExample");
        pane1 = new JPanel();
        pane2 = new JPanel();
        pane3 = new JPanel();
        field1 = new JTextField(10);
        field2 = new JTextField(10);
        field3 = new JTextField(20);
        table = new JTable();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

        pane1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pane2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pane3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        pane1.add(field1);
        pane1.add(field2);
        pane2.add(jsp);
        pane2.add(field3);
        pane3.add(new JLabel("Something else"));

        frame.add(pane1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(pane2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(pane3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new LayoutManagerExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using GridBagLayout didn't alleviate the problem. The panel2 components were centered even when using Insets. The code is posted in the question above. Thanks

Comment: Yo didn't posted how it should look like as @AndrewThompson said in his comment above

Comment: Thank you Frakcool for the pic. But I was trying to specify table.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,300)). I understand from your comment that GridLayout cannot do that. That's why I was using GridBagLayout. Thx.

Comment: @user2654788 I'm confused, what you mean? Yes, `GridLayout` won't allow you to set up your own dimensions.

Comment: Sorry I meant table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,300). Basically, I wanted the table component's width to be 600 in its own panel, regardless of the GridBagLayout specified in the panel above. Please check the code I posted for GridBagLayout above. Thanks

Comment: Does it needs to be a `GridBagLayout`?