# Java: How do I get the text of two JLabels when copying JLabel's text with TransferHandler?

Tags: copy, handler, jlabel, drag

How do I get the text of two JLabels when copying JLabel's text with TransferHandler?

Label1111111 How can I keep the text of both JLabels when copied to Label2222222.

For this reason, I will take control of two Jlabel's texts. This shape can only get the text of JLabel, which was first held. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
public class deneme2 extends JFrame {

    private static final int COPY = 0;
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    deneme2 frame = new deneme2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public deneme2() {      
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();    

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label1111111", JLabel.CENTER);        
        handlerLabel(label1);
        label1.addMouseListener(listener);
        panel.add(label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label2222222", JLabel.CENTER);
        handlerLabel(label2);   
        label2.addMouseListener(listener);   
        panel.add(label2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        contentPane.add(panel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    private void handlerLabel (JLabel lbl)
    {
         lbl.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text") {
                @Override
                protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
                    if (action == COPY){
                        ((JLabel)lbl.getDropTarget().getDropTargetContext().getComponent()).getText();
                        //((JLabel) source).setText("LabelEmpty");                                      
                        }
                }             
            });
    }

    private class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = comp.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(comp, e, TransferHandler.COPY);   
        }          
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe in this way. I added inner class `MyLabel` and console output in your `handlerLabel`. Ctrl+v this under your `main`. It will print to console the `original` `String` property of each `MyLabels`.

```
    public class MyLabel extends JLabel {
        String original;

        public MyLabel (String text)
        {
            super(text);
            this.original=text;
        }

        public String getOriginal() {
            return original;
        }

        public void setOriginal(String original) {
            this.original = original;
        }

    }
    public deneme2() {      
        JPanel panel= new JPanel();
        MouseListener listener = (MouseListener) new DragMouseAdapter();    

        MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel("Label1111111");        
        handlerLabel(label1);
        label1.addMouseListener(listener);
        panel.add(label1);

        MyLabel label2 = new MyLabel("Label2222222");
        handlerLabel(label2);   
        label2.addMouseListener(listener);   
        panel.add(label2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        contentPane.add(panel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

        private void handlerLabel(MyLabel lbl) {
        lbl.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text") {
            @Override
            protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
                if (action == COPY) {
                    System.out.println(((MyLabel) lbl.getDropTarget().getDropTargetContext().getComponent()).getOriginal());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

Edit: check this out. Ctrl+V this under your main. It will print to console text of source label and text of target label, also the `original` property. Class `MyLabel` implements [`DropTargetListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DropTargetListener.html) , which is then registered by `new DropTarget(this, this)`. Then we define what will happen in overriden `drop` method.

```
 public class MyLabel extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener {

        String original;

        public MyLabel(String text) {
            super(text);
            this.original = text;

            new DropTarget(this, this);

            this.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));

            final MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent me) {
                    final MyLabel label = (MyLabel) me.getSource();
                    final TransferHandler handler = label.getTransferHandler();
                    handler.exportAsDrag(label, me, TransferHandler.COPY);
                }
            };

            this.addMouseListener(listener);
        }

        public String getOriginal() {
            return original;
        }

        public void setOriginal(String original) {
            this.original = original;
        }

        @Override
        public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

        }

        @Override
        public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

        }

        @Override
        public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {

        }

        @Override
        public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {

        }

        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            try {
                final String sourceString = (String) dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor("application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=java.lang.String"));
                System.out.println("Source: " + sourceString + " target: " + this.getText());
                this.setText(sourceString);
                System.out.println("Original target: "+this.getOriginal());
            } catch (final UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public deneme2() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel("Label1111111a");
        panel.add(label1);

        MyLabel label2 = new MyLabel("Label2222222b");
        panel.add(label2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        contentPane.add(panel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT2: Following code generates <strike>this result</strike> see result at the end of this answer:[image: Label111111]

or

[image: label2222222]

It also prints `original` property to console. Those could be organised differently (`MyLabel`, `MyLabelTransferable`, `MyLabelDropTargetListener`, `MyLabelTransferHandler` classes, just to give an idea for future refactoring) but it works in this way too. Consider it a quickfix for your use case.

So main class is this:

```
 public class Deneme2 extends JFrame {

    private static final int COPY = 0;
    private static final int NONE = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Deneme2 mainFrame = new Deneme2();
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {//let's get that frame on EDT rollin lambda style:)
          mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      });

    }

    public Deneme2() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MyLabel label1 = new MyLabel("Label1111111a");
        panel.add(label1, BorderLayout.WEST);

        MyLabel label2 = new MyLabel("Label2222222b");
        panel.add(label2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.add(panel);
    }
}
```

Then MyLabel.java :

```
    public class MyLabel extends JLabel implements DropTargetListener, Transferable {

    String original;
    protected static final DataFlavor MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + "; class=\"" + MyLabel.class.getCanonicalName() + "\"",
             "MyLabel label");
    protected static final DataFlavor[] SUPPORTED_FLAVORS = {MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR};

    public MyLabel(String text) {
        super(text);
        this.original = text;
        new DropTarget(this, this);
        this.setTransferHandler(new MyLabelTransferHandler()); //here we use our custom TransferHandler
        final MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent me) {
                final MyLabel label = (MyLabel) me.getSource();
                final TransferHandler handler = label.getTransferHandler();
                handler.exportAsDrag(label, me, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
        };
        this.addMouseListener(listener);

    }

    public String getOriginal() {
        return original;
    }

    public void setOriginal(String original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        if (dtde.getTransferable().isDataFlavorSupported(MyLabel.MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR)) {
            System.out.println("Drop accept - MyLabel");
            dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
        } else {
            dtde.rejectDrag();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        //System.out.println("Drag over");
    }

    @Override
    public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("Action changed");
    }

    @Override
    public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
        System.out.println("Exited");

    }

    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
        System.out.println("Drop detected");

        if (dtde.getTransferable().isDataFlavorSupported(MyLabel.MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR)) {
            Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();

            if (t.isDataFlavorSupported(MyLabel.MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR)) {
                try {
                    Object transferData = t.getTransferData(MyLabel.MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR);

                    if (transferData instanceof MyLabel) {
                        MyLabel mySourceLabel = (MyLabel) transferData;

                        if (!(mySourceLabel.equals(this))) {
                            dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
                            this.setText(mySourceLabel.getText());
                            mySourceLabel.setText("Empty");
                            System.out.println(mySourceLabel.getOriginal() + " " + this.getOriginal());
                        } else {
                            dtde.rejectDrop();
                            System.out.println("Drop rejected - the same MyLabel");
                        }
                    } else {
                        dtde.rejectDrop();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                    dtde.rejectDrop();
                }
            } else {
                dtde.rejectDrop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return SUPPORTED_FLAVORS;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor.equals(MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR) || flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);

    }

    @Override
    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (flavor.equals(MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR)) {
            return this;
        } else if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            return this.getText();
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
    }
}
```

And then MyLabelTransferHandler.java :

```
public class MyLabelTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        return (support.getComponent() instanceof MyLabel) && support.isDataFlavorSupported(MyLabel.MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(JComponent src, Transferable transferable) {
        return src instanceof MyLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY;
    }

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        Transferable t = (MyLabel)c;
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
        System.out.println("Export done.");
    }
}
```

After final edit result looks like this:

[image: final result]

Little clarification:

```
protected static final DataFlavor MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + "; class=\"" + MyLabel.class.getCanonicalName() + "\"",
             "MyLabel label");
```

in MyLabel. That's important line. This will make `getTransferData()` return the same instance of `MyLabel`. If you would do it like:

```
protected static final DataFlavor MYLABEL_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(MyLabel.class, "MyLabel label");
```

you won't be able to change `mySourceLabel` text to "Empty" in overridden `drop()` method, since you would be given a copy of that object.

Also [Why shouldn't you extend JFrame and other components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components) . And you can provide checking for "Empty" text (if `getText()` returns "Empty", then don't change text in target `MyLabel`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I drag Label11111, I need to get the value in Label22222 and check it. I can not get Label22222 in this way. If you could help with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So when I drag Label1111 I need to getText () in Label2222 to check it.

Comment: I can not thank you enough. Thank you so much. Finally, let me ask you something else. How can I make the source 'empty' after dragging?

Comment: @MeHcKeR well, that's a little more complicated. We need to obtain `MyLabel` from `getTransferData`, and to do that we need to create `DataFlavor` for `MyLabel`, extend `TransferHandler` and make `MyLabel `implement `Transferable`. In 15min I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're gorgeous. I integrated the project. I was confused, I would have solved this problem without you.