# Java swing two indipendent frames

Tags: java, swing, authentication, frames

I have a main frame of my application and i want to have another frame for login. So i have written two classes: a Main class and a LoginFrame class.

```
/*Imported classes*/

public class Main {

    private JFrame frame;
    private LoginFrame loginFrame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBounds(10, 10, 426, 243);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        loginFrame = new LoginFrame("Login...");
        loginFrame.setVisible(true);
        loginFrame.pack();
        
    }
}
```

```
/*Imported classes*/
public class LoginFrame extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField usernameField;
    private JPasswordField passwordField;
    
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoginFrame window = new LoginFrame("Login...");
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }*/

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public LoginFrame(String title) {
        
    

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */

        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 10, 426, 243);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User:");
        userLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 14));
        userLabel.setEnabled(true);
        userLabel.setBounds(41, 78, 45, 13);
        panel.add(userLabel);
        
        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
        passwordLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        passwordLabel.setBounds(41, 124, 76, 13);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        
        usernameField = new JTextField();
        usernameField.setBounds(165, 75, 173, 19);
        panel.add(usernameField);
        usernameField.setColumns(10);
        
        passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        passwordField.setColumns(10);
        passwordField.setBounds(165, 123, 173, 19);
        panel.add(passwordField);
        
        JLabel loginLabel = new JLabel("Enter Username and Password");
        loginLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        loginLabel.setBounds(79, 22, 259, 13);
        panel.add(loginLabel);
        
        JButton resetLoginButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetLoginButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        resetLoginButton.setBounds(318, 189, 85, 21);
        panel.add(resetLoginButton);
        
        JButton okLoginButton = new JButton("Ok");
        okLoginButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        okLoginButton.setBounds(217, 189, 85, 21);
        panel.add(okLoginButton);
    }
    
}
```

what i get is the two frames:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl2GO.png]

When i open the login frame there is nothing (buttons and text fields).What is the problem? Is it a right way to implement a login frame?

I expect two different frame the main one empty. The second one with two fields one for username and the other with password and two buttons.

Comment: Login has to frames (extends from and creates its own) - which one are you actually using? As a general rule, don’t extend directly from top level containers like JFrame

Comment: Hard programming the positions of the components is really painful and time consuming, use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead

Comment: see [Why shouldn't you extend JFrame and other components?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143923/85421) and the duplicate it points to [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22003802/85421)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When i open the login frame there is nothing (buttons and text fields).

Of course.

> What is the problem?

You never add any components to your `LoginFrame`. You instead create a *separate* `JFrame`, add some components to that, and then do nothing further with it.

Comment: On the main frame have to be nothing because i haven't added nothing. The problem is on the login frame. There where i have added two bottons and two label and text fields.

Comment: @user1420240 you dont seem to understand, you're adding it on a frame within the LoginFrame class not the login frame itself

Comment: @user1420240, I urge you to drop the `LoginFrame` class, and in its place use an ordinary `JFrame` populated with the components appropriate for the role of accepting user login information.  It would be better form, and you're already most of the way there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
loginFrame.pack();
```

The `pack()` statement will cause the frame to be displayed at its preferred size.

Since you are using a null layout the frame does NOT have a preferred size.

The solution is to NOT use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Also, note that the content pane of a frame is a JPanel, so there is no need for you to create a separate panel to add to the frame.

Read the tutorial for Swing basics.

Comment: Yes,definitely.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [John Bollinger on the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77455717/21252090).

What you're doing wrong is adding the components on a frame inside the `LoginFrame` class. What am I yapping about? well look here

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(0, 10, 426, 243);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setLayout(null);
```

What are you adding your panel to? **Well `JFrame frame` inside your `LoginFrame` class!**

Now I want you to look here

```
loginFrame = new LoginFrame("Login...");
loginFrame.setVisible(true);
loginFrame.pack();
```

What are you making visible? **The login frame!**

The second mistake you are making is using `loginFrame.pack()` but read [camickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77455831/21252090) to know more.

How can you fix this? You have two easy options.

> Option A. Create a getter for the `frame` in `LoginFrame`

Well this is quite straight foward and it works, create a getter for the `frame` and instead of using `loginFrame.setVisible(true);` use `loginFrame.getFrame().setVisible(true);`

> Option B. Delete the frame

Just delete the frame object. Replace anything like `frame.getContentPane().add(panel);` with `getContentPane().add(panel);` this will use `this.getContentPane()...` which means that you use the `LoginFrame` instead.

And most importantly remove the `pack()` line!

[image]

This should help you and you're gonna get something like this ;) I believe that's what you wanted.